# Best practice to manage Queue policies in Spring-amqp project

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have an application that includes a RabbitMq Admin module to automatically manage the RMQ depending on the application state.

Until now I have used x-arguments approach to manage parameters (such as TTL), however, I have recently learned that RMQ suggests using the [policies](https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html) as the recommended way to manage such parameters.

I want to migrate to this approach, but there is one risk that stands out to me: if the queue is removed or the cluster fails for any reason, my application needs to be aware of this fact and be able to recover the RMQ configuration to its correct state.

Spring-amqp does not provide any out-of-the-box way to do this so the naive approach here seems to be to configure a periodic task to monitor the policies and update them if they ever go out of sync. At the same time, a periodic job is a code that will need to be maintained and thus feels like a luxury to use for a reason like this.

What does SO think, can I state that the Spring-amqp way (x-arguments) is better in a Spring project, or should I go chasing the Rabbit team's best practices and over-engineer myself a policy manager?

Comment: I suggest you ask on the rabbitmq-users Google Group - the RabbitMQ experts don't monitor Stack Overflow closely, but they are active over there.